# what trigonometrically satisfies $x^2+y^4=1$ belong too?

Tags: trigonometry

Plotting $x^2+y^4=1$ gives some 'squat cuircular type shape but spesically what satisfies these conditions in terms of sines and cosines ect? (An analogy  would be circles $x^2+y^2=1$ that are satisfied by the standard sine cosine relation)

Comment: $x=\sin\theta$, $y=\sqrt{\cos\theta}$?

Comment: You are probably asking us to **express $x^2+y^4=1$ in a parametric form**.

Comment: $y=\cos t$, $x=\sin t\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t}$...

Answer (score 2):

You can call $y^2=z$. Then, your relation reads
$$x^2+z^2=1$$
and you can suppose $x=\cos(\theta),\;z=\sin(\theta)$. Then $y$ can be $y=\pm\sqrt{\sin(\theta)}$